# How to compare string list in if statement?

Tags: python

I wanted to call a string from another class and compare whether the string value match from the define string in the variable. But when runing the code it doesn't compare properly.Thanks for the reply.

```
class TasteMaker:
   
    print(" Nice! Now your maggie is half cooked, it's time to add the taste maker. "
          " \n Taste maker is the flavour of maggie and it is recommended to add it"
          " but some people keep it simple without adding it. "
          "\n So want to add or not add the taste maker. " " \n A.add \n B.don't add ")
    time.sleep(3)
    taste = input(" >>> ").lower()


class Time:
    

    minutes = TasteMaker.taste
    addY = ['add', 'A']

    if minutes == addY:
        print("Nice Choice!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("\n Now for the final touch. The last and the first step is the most crucial step in cooking."
              " Chose whether to keep in for full 10min, 15min or 20min"
              "\n A.10min"
              "\n B.15min"
              "\n C.20min")
        final = input(" >>> ")

    else:
        print(" Ok! You chose not to add the taste maker.")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("\n Now for the final touch. The last and the first step is the most crucial step in cooking."
              " Chose whether to keep in for full 10min, 15min or 20min"
              "\n A.10min"
              "\n B.15min"
              "\n C.20min")
        final = input(" >>> ")
```

Comment: Why do you have classes here where you make no instances of them, and they don't have any methods? It seems like you have a basic misunderstanding of the purpose of classes...

Comment: i am sorry i am learning by myself and got started..can u explain how can i compare string in the if statement when the variable is define.

Comment: Per the duplicate, seems like you just want to change `if minutes == addY:` to `if minutes in addY:`. Not that `minutes` or `addY` make any sense as variable names.

Comment: i tried using == but the if function doesn't call rather else is called..so iam confused is there any other way around it

Comment: You're not reading what I wrote. I didn't say to use `==`.

Comment: I am so SORRY! I was just lost trying to find the solution.. It worked.. the "in" that's the key word i was searching for not "is" or "=="..Thank you big time..and again i am really sorry